# Cakephp - Saving related models

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have the following relationships between my models:

```
Assignment hasMany Question
Question belongsTo Assignment
Question hasMany Answer
Answer belongsTo Question
```

I would like to have a single form that can save the assignment, the questions, and the answers.

The form is almost working, it saves the assignment information and the questions, but not the answers.

Assignments Controller Create action:

```
function create() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {

        var_dump($this->data);

        unset($this->Assignment->Question->validate['assignment_id']);
        unset($this->Assignment->Question->Answer->validate['question_id']);
        $this->Assignment->saveAll($this->data, array('validate' => 'first'));
    }
}
```

create.ctp

```
Create new assignment
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('assignment', array('action' => 'create'));
echo $this->Form->input('Assignment.title');
echo $this->Form->input('Assignment.type');
echo $this->Form->input('Question.0.question');
echo $this->Form->input('Question.0.Answer.0.answer');
echo $this->Form->end('Create');

?>
```

Comment: **speculation** perhaps Cake is having problems saving to 3 different models at once. For the sake of testing, separate the `assignment` creation and just have `question` and `answers`. If that works as intended, you can debug further, but if not, the problem could lie elsewhere.

Comment: could it be because I have no direct link between Assignment and Answer?

Comment: That's a definite possibility and would make sense. I'm not sure of a workaround, or if indeed that's the case though.

Comment: Off-topic, if a question has many answers, what model will be using for responses to a question when taking the assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to save everything independently.

What do you think of this possibility?

```
function create() {

    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Assignment->save($this->data)) {
            foreach($this->data['Question'] as $question) {
                $this->Question->create();
                $question['assignment_id'] = $this->Assignment->getLastInsertId();

                if($this->Question->save($question) && $failed == false) {
                    foreach ($question['Answer'] as $answer) {
                        $this->Answer->create();
                        $answer['question_id'] = $this->Question->getLastInsertId();

                        $this->Answer->save($answer);                           
                    }
                }


            }
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: you should validate all the data first ($this->Assignment->validates(), $this->Assignment->Question->validates(), $this->Assignment->Question->Answer->validates()) in case some data fails halfway through the save. And you shouldn't use $uses or loadModel if not really needed.

Comment: is there any way of starting a transaction in the controller?, in case validation fails....

Comment: cake validates entirely in php. And I don't think you want to use transaction in cake, it's messy..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because:

```
Assignment hasMany Question
```

But Assignment does not have Answer.

If you find('all') on Assignment with the correct recursive option, it will show all entries on related models. But when creating a new assignment it will only save the tables directly related. And Answer isn't one.

In order to create a new answer, either you make an association between Assignment and Answer or make a function to create the answer after saving the creating Assignment.

You could on assignments_controller.php

```
function create() {
    $this->Assignment->saveAll($this->data, array('validate' => 'first'));
    $this->loadModel('Answer');
    $data[] = array(
        'question_id' => GET_THE_ID_OF_LAST_QUESTION_INSERTED
    );
    $this->Answer->save($data);
}
```

I'm not sure, but I think you can get the id of last question inserted just using:

```
$this->Assignment->Question->id;
```

By the way... Why would you want to automatically create a new answer after creating a new assignment/question? It makes no sense.

Comment: By answer I mean possible answer, since I am creating a multiple choice type assignment.

Comment: Should I create a relationship between the possible answers and the assignment?

Comment: I see. You don't need to create the relationship between answers and assignment because it does not exist on the normal forms. Just create/save the answers after creating a new Assignment. You can use afterSave() [book.cakephp.org/view/1053/afterSave](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1053/afterSave)